# Uninstalling PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I was wondering if you uninstall phpmyadmin from you sever, will it disrupt anything that is already on the server, besides phpmyadmin of course?

Comment: PHPmyAdmin is just a set of php files that provide a graphical interface for accessing mysql databases on your system. Deleting the pma files should have no side-effects ... ***except for users being forced to learn raw SQL***. Of course, if you used a package manager like `yum` or `apt-get` to install it, you should uninstall using the same method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how it was originally installed.  If you installed phpmyadmin yourself you can simply remove the contents.  If it came pre-installed by the OS (eg Linux) you should attempt to use the built-in uninstaller (apt, yum, etc.)  If it came with a server suite (XAMPP, WAMP, etc.) I would recommend removing the entire suite and then reinstalling without phpmyadmin.

Comment: I'm going to bet that PhpMyAdmin is not pre-installed in any common Linux distribution.

Comment: As the package is offered thru repositories, it won't be too weird to find it installed from apt/synaptic/sw-center/yast,...

Answer (score 1):

As PhpMyAdmin is just a set of script, uninstalling or deleting it will not affect any other scripts as long as you leave the database in place.